# How can I replace newline with space in between each item using enumerator?

Tags: enumerate

When I use `enumerate`. I want to remove newline in between each item and just add space instead.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Following steps: Step 1. Step 2. Step 3.

Following steps:
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={},label={}]
    \item Step 1.
    \item Step 2.
    \item Step 3.
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

output (first line is the wanted output):
[image]

On the second line, my code puts extra space at the beginning of the first item, is it possible to prevent it?

Comment: The package [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and then set a list in-line (see p. 14 section 4).

Comment: I have added `/!/!` to the beginging of the first item, seems like it also helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use `enumerate*`, as direct input is much easier.

Anyway, here's how.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Following steps: Step 1. Step 2. Step 3.

Following steps:
\begin{enumerate*}[before=\unskip,itemjoin={},label={}]
    \item Step 1.
    \item Step 2.
    \item Step 3.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean by `direct input`? There is no specific reason for `enumerate*` I can try to do `set a list in-line` as well